# How to display wp-errors in custom login.php from functions.php

Tags: wordpress, error-handling, display

I am trying to get wp-errors on my login.php i do get the error in the url through the function that is created in function.php.

This is in my functions.php

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user) {
    $login_page  = home_url('/login/');
    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        //Login failed, find out why...
        $error_types = array_keys($user->errors);
        if (is_array($error_types) && !empty($error_types)) {
            $error_type = $error_types[0];
        }
        wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=failed&reason=" . $error_type ); 
        exit;
    } else {
        //Login OK - redirect to another page?
        return home_url();
    }
}
```

But i also want the error to be displayed on my login.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create *custom template* for your login page. [See reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page).

After that you can use `$_GET['reason']` to display the reason variable value inside your template. [See reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php).

You can do something like this:

```
<?php

if( isset( $_GET['reason'] ) ){
    $reason = $_GET['reason'];
    echo "Login error: " . $reason;
}

?>
```